# How to get rid of this error message in RStudio: Error creating notebook: Parser error

Tags: parsing, rstudio

I was working on a R notebook and when I saved it I encountered this error message:

> Error creating notebook: Parser error: while parsing a block mapping
>   at line 1, column 1 did not find expected key at line 1, column 40.

I am not sure what it is and how to fix it.

Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error (Mac OS). It worked for me to shut down RStudio and remove the hidden folder .Proj.user/ located under the project directory. Then after restarting RStudio and reopening the notebook files things worked as normal.

Answer (score 1):

I had this error and I fixed it by changing the intro on my Rnotebook. This is what it was originally (notice the double quotations):

```
---
title: ""This is my Title""
output: html_notebook
---
```

TO:

```
---
title: "This is my Title"
output: html_notebook
---
```

The issue was in the first title I had 2 quotation marks instead of one. I deleted the extra set and my issue was fixed.